# Close Error window that appears when debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm debugging and encounter an error a giant tool tip appears covering the screen. I can't see anything else. How can I close this or disable it?

Here is a screen shot (the bottom half is cut off but is nearly full height of the editor): 
[image]

I would be happy to remove the error tooltip all together if possible. I'll check the error message in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to close the tool tip. The tool tip is inserted between the code and does not cover anything. You should be able to scroll the window to see further down as well.
[image]